# Centering an HTML div overlay on an SVG chart

Tags: d3.js

I've got an SVG pie chart that I've drawn with D3, and I've got a small HTML div that is supposed to appear when one mouses over the various slices of the pie chart, like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/adamehirsch/bzSpW/

The problem comes in positioning that HTML  overlay. Currently, I'm having to explicitly position it relative to the entire page. The below comes in around line 145 of the javascript:

```
d3.select("#bracketsTip")
    .style("left", "420px") // this is dumb
    .style("top", "320px")  // and unnecessary, I'm sure
.transition()
    .duration(250)
    .style("opacity", 1.0);
```

I'm looking for a way to have the HTML div appear centered on the pie chart without having to specify the pixel offset myself.  Suggestions?

Comment: Do it in pure SVG, will make yout life easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed you had jQuery loaded in your fiddle. You could do something like:

```
var leftPos = width / 2 - $("#bracketsTip").width() / 2
  , topPos = height / 2;

    d3.select("#bracketsTip")
        .style("left", leftPos + "px")
        .style("top", topPos + "px")
    .transition()
        .duration(250)
        .style("opacity", 1.0);
```

Now if you change the width and height of your pie chart, the overlay will stay centered.

Comment: That is *precisely* the elegant solution I was hoping was out there. Man, I hadn't even thought of getting the dimensions from jQuery. *facepalm*